# How to allow clicking on elements behind elements with a higher z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I would like to put a reflection over the entire page. I have a transparent png that fades from white to transparent and I would like it to fill the browser and be displayed above everything else but allow the user to click on everything behind it, not be able to be dragged, and work in all browsers. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but I can picture what you're after perfectly. Hopefully someone has a crafty solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events), which [works everywhere except](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) IE10 and older.

A blog post with more information:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/

Comment: That's pretty cool, here's a demo if anyone wants to check it out (worked in FF6): http://jsfiddle.net/ndQdj/ - Yeah this seems impossible cross browser but it seems like such a simple thing to want to do that it's surprising how difficult/impossible it is.

Comment: Is there a way to apply pointer-events: none if the browser is safari chrome or firefox but hide the reflection png if in opera or IE?

Comment: @user852974: IE is easy, just use a conditional stylesheet, [IE hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter), or my favorite method: [IE only classes on the `<html>` element](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/). It's really the kind of thing that can make your whole site unusable, so *definitely* make sure you have a fallback way to disable it, or maybe you can detect `pointer-events` support and *enable* it? Not sure how, just an idea.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: JavaScript *can* detect support for `pointer-events`, but Opera reports a false positive (or something).

Comment: Answer accepted so early? I was expecting an epic slew of hacks to come flooding in.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the content backgrounds transparent, or with transparent png's?

Or set the opacity for the content as if it's faded into the background. Not sure what you're trying to achieve though I'm sure you can get a similar effect if you try a new approach. From a design point of view I can't imagine how a div over the main content could create an effect not achievable via other methods.

Comment: It's different because you can overlay the semi-transparent div over something else, like a mask/filter. Not the same as a background.

Comment: @Wesley-Murch Hmm I see though personally I would avoid pointer-events. There's so much you can do without it, e.g http://robertnyman.com/css3/pointer-events/pointer-events.html can be replicated by duplicating the div containing the text,place in another div, placing it directly over, changing the width and using overflow:hidden.